# Automatic power switching, grounds not connected

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, switches

I'm currently working on a project that requires a 24V DC input. That is no problem, as I have that power supply available. However, the project should also remain working when the supply fails or becomes unavailable. For that, I want to automatically switch to the backup supply. This will most likely just be a battery, but can also be another generator.

There are a few ways to switch from power input automatically, but there is one important rule that I have to follow in this sector: the grounds may not be connected.

[This, for example, is no solution because of that rule.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/213260/247398)

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: How do you expect the current to return if the grounds are not connected? What exactly do you mean by this, the grounds of the two sources or the grounds of a given source and the load? We need more details, and a schematic would help.

Comment: Both sources' grounds will have to be connected to the load at some point; best thing you can do is make sure they are not connected to the load at the same time (and so to each other) by switching both plus and ground simultaneously when you switch over to another source. How fast you would need to do that and the implementation depends on specs we don't have.

Comment: Let's start with a very warm welcome to the site and thanks for writing a detailed question. It outlines your problem well but is ambiguous, missing the technical information people will need to construct any worthwhile answers. Please edit your question and add a schematic showing exactly what circuit you are trying to make. Please explain the situation that requires it, including the 'sector' that will use it. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 

@ElliotAlderson: I mean the grounds of the sources, I am sorry. I don't have a schematics for this yet.

Comment: @ocrdu: Yes, that is most likely what I want. I am wondering how I would do that. Let's assume we have a whole second available.

Comment: See answer. An electromechanical relay will switch in about 5 to 15ms, so that would be fast enough if you have a whole second, which, by the way, is an eternity for this sort of application; the power supply unit of the load, if any, would have to be able to bridge that second at worst-case current being pulled by the load. But if you spec one second, then a relay will do, if the control block (see answer) is also fast enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the grounds may not be connected.

I hope it's meant that the main and backup supplies' grounds may not be connected.

Here's a concept diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2wJET.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Main and Backup supplies do not share the grounds here. CONTROL BLOCK is supplied from the Main supply. This block drives the relay and directs the SYSTEM's input to the Main supply by default. When the CONTROL BLOCK decides the Main supply is faulty (e.g. too low voltage) or the Main supply is not applied (i.e. unavailable) then the relay's contacts will switch to NC position and the SYSTEM will get the supply input from the Backup supply.

hth.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohat! This helps a lot. :)

Comment: @RobinMartijn please note that the relay here is a Break-Before-Make type. So, when the supply is switched to the Backup the SYSTEM may stop because it will not get any supply for a short time. This is a problem that needs to be solved. Depending on the power requirements of the SYSTEM, capacitors placed across the supply input may solve the problem. But, the higher the power requirement, the bigger the capacitor you should place.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out explicitely. :)